# Where is the Visual Studio Macro for FrameworkSDKDir?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

There used to be a Macro for `FrameworkSDKDir` for .net apps in the `Build Events` tab. As mentioned [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx), that's:

> The directory into which you installed the .NET Framework.

Now on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, it's not in the Macros list. I verified, and I *do* have the Windows 10 SDK installed. The path should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\` . I know I can just hard code that value, but there's a reason for Macros…

So, is there some way to get it back?

Comment: It only ever existed in C++ projects.  It still does.

Comment: @HansPassant I used it (only) in C# projects in post-build events. It worked fine on VS2010/VS2013 on Windows 7.

Comment: Hmya, your VS version so very often is different from mine.  Yours has a habit of adding 1 + 1 and ends up with 11 instead of 2.   Managed projects are not supposed to need the SDK.  [Read this again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).